How to create new Fsx share noninteractively?
When running Invoke-Command to create Fsx share I am prompted for credentials. I would like to create Fsx share using SSM Command (no interactive user).
AWS Documentation says:
Example: Create a new SMB share named Marketing.

[fs-0123456789abcdef0] PS>> New-FSxSmbShare -Name "New Share" -Path "D:\share\Marketing" -Description "Marketing team share" -FolderEnumerationMode AccessBased -EncryptData $true
<Enter your credentials when prompted>

Documentation says that command New-FSxSmbShare uses Kerberos authentication. Kerberos supports Windows Integrated Authentication.
How to create AWS FSX share as non interactive user?

Solution is to pass variable with keyword $Using
$credential = Get-Credential; # Use method which suits you
Invoke-Command -ConfigurationName FSxRemoteAdmin -ComputerName amznfsxtgsiezzi.staging365.corp -ErrorVariable errmsg -ScriptBlock { New-FSxSmbShare  -Path D:\Share10 -Name Share10 -Credential $Using:credential  }


